# SQS Lambda - Redrive Policy vs DeadLetterConfig

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have set up lambda integration to SQS with fixed reserved concurrency to throttle requests to a backend service. I need to use a DLQ to track and store errors.

What are the differences in behavior between using the Redrive Policy of the SQS vs the DeadLetterConfig of the lambda function?

I am particularly interested in the behavior when there are huge amounts of messages in the Queue but with limited lambda concurrency.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The dead-letter queue that you configure on a function is used for the function's **asynchronous** invocations, not for event source queues. Lambda polls the sqs queue and invokes your function **synchronously** with an event that contains queue messages.  So if you use SQS as event source, DeadLetterConfig is of no use. You have to configure DLQ with re-drive policy for the source SQS.

Source : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html

Comment: How does RedrivePolicy handle throttling? WIll every message be processed at least once?

Comment: If you configure Source SQS with RedrivePolicy as MaxReceives 3. Then after lambda receives the message more than 3 times, the message will be automatically moved to DLQ.  
 **1st Receive** -> Lambda Throttled  -> Message will re-appear in Source SQS after visibility timeout, 
 **2nd Receive** -> Lambda Throttled  -> Message will re-appear in Source SQS after visibility timeout ,
**3rd Receive** -> Lambda Throttled  -> Message will re-appear in Source SQS after visibility timeout,
**4th Receive** -> As MaxReceive met, message will be moved to DLQ without processing.